# create report from external big data at sql database at sharepoint 2016

Tags: library, sql, database-server, external

I need to create a report from an external SQL database and run the report at SharePoint 2016.
The SQL database size was big around 5 GB, How can I do it?

I think to create a procedure at SQL database level to read external bulk data and then create the report at SharePoint.
There are only Library Report, Are there any solution to generate and run a report at SharePoint ??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [SSRS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/reporting-services-report-server-sharepoint-mode?view=sql-server-2016).

First step would be to install and configure SSRS on the SQL Server if it's not done yet. Then, you need to [create a new SSRS report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-basic-table-report-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver15). When you are done with your report, you can either post a hyperlink to it in SharePoint, or, if you are using the SSRS in the SharePoint Mode, you can show reports right inside the SharePoint site.

If you don't want to deal with the SSRS in the SharePoint mode, you can simply display the SSRS reports as iFrames inside SharePoint.